# observer design pattern class issue

Tags: design-patterns

observer pattern is used for notify functionality,  in the actual implementation, few classed may have blocking calls in the notify function. Basically my question is , how to avoid  notify function getting blocked.  Because if it get gets blocked due to one class then it blocks every other call. As in below example of update() function  makes a blocking in the class DivObserver.
Modified below class from original to show blocking statement in one of class:

```
  class DivObserver: public Observer {
    public:
     DivObserver(Subject *mod, int div): Observer(mod, div){}
      void update()
       {
       pthread_mutex_lock();
       /*blocking statement call*/
        pthread_mutex_unlock();
   }
 };

  -----------------------------------text book example---------------------                       ---------------

    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

  class Subject {
// 1. "independent" functionality
    vector < class Observer * > views; // 3. Coupled only to "interface"
    int value;
    public:
    void attach(Observer *obs) 
    {
        views.push_back(obs);
     }
     void setVal(int val) 
     {
        value = val;
        notify();
     }
    int getVal() {
        return value;
    }
    void notify();
 };

 class Observer {
    // 2. "dependent" functionality
    Subject *model;
    int denom;
    public:
     Observer(Subject *mod, int div) {
        model = mod;
         denom = div;
        // 4. Observers register themselves with the Subject
        model->attach(this);
    }
    virtual void update() = 0;
    protected:
    Subject *getSubject() {
       return model;
    }
    int getDivisor() {
        return denom;
    }
};

void Subject::notify() {
   // 5. Publisher broadcasts
   for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++)
    views[i]->update();
}

class DivObserver: public Observer {
  public:
     DivObserver(Subject *mod, int div): Observer(mod, div){}
    void update() {
       // 6. "Pull" information of interest
       int v = getSubject()->getVal(), d = getDivisor();
       cout << v << " div " << d << " is " << v / d << '\n';
   }
};

 class ModObserver: public Observer {
  public:
     ModObserver(Subject *mod, int div): Observer(mod, div){}
    void update() {
        int v = getSubject()->getVal(), d = getDivisor();
        cout << v << " mod " << d << " is " << v % d << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
  Subject subj;
   DivObserver divObs1(&subj, 4); // 7. Client configures the number and
   DivObserver divObs2(&subj, 3); //    type of Observers
   ModObserver modObs3(&subj, 3);
   subj.setVal(14);
 }
```

Comment: The most obvious solution is to document the observable as "Observers shouldn't block. If your observer blocks, too bad for you. I warned you".

Comment: I'll put it back to zero :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observer pattern is solving one problem at expense of creating a couple of brand new ones. That is so typical for virtually every pattern out there.

The trick is to know how to control behavior of the pattern. In case of the Observer, benefit you are getting is that you can effectively call back a number of other objects without ever depending on their types. That is good part about the Observer. The bad part is that once you place a call back, you are at the mercy of the object you have called.

Yet another problem about the Observer, which developers often forget about, is that the subscriber has to unsubscribe before it plans to die. Otherwise, observable object will keep it alive in systems with garbage collections. In systems with explicit memory deallocation, observable object will hold a dangling reference, which is even worse.

There is no nice way out of these two issues. They are the signature of the Observer pattern as much as the notification concept is. We could argue that it is possible to turn implementation to asynchronous version, even with timeouts, etc. But that would be way outside the scope of the Observable pattern, and that would be a totally different design.

Bottom line: Yes, if observer object blocks, then the observable object is blocked, and the client who placed a call to the observable object is blocked too.